# MYSQL partitioning existing table using a foreign key

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Hi I have a table which contains over 2 million records. I want to partition this table using a foreign key called `venue_id` which will then speed up some of the reports I have created.

Here is a picture of the table structure that I am trying to partition.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtc89.jpg)

I have tried running this code:

```
ALTER TABLE wifi_client_connection
    PARTITION BY KEY(venue_id)
    PARTITIONS 500;
```

But I kept getting this error: `A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

I have researched the error and I think it is because `venue_id` isnt unique because it is a foreign key.

Comment: I think it's the primary key (`id`) that gives the error ... anyway, there are limitations when partitioning and using foreign keys: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html

Comment: @valicu2000 Thankd for the reply, If we forgot it was a foreign key would there be anyway to partition using it?

Comment: Partitioning is not a tool to speed up a query, that is what indexes are for! Querys that use the partitioning key are as fast as before, all other queries will be (at least a bit) slower because of the overhead (of e.g. reading and merging partitioned indexes other than the partitioing key). Partitioning is a tool to solve specific administration problems and comes with some limitations (e.g. for unique keys and the performance *decrease*), so unless you have a problem that actually profits from (or requires) partitioning, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @LukeRayner - Have you become @Lukerayner?  I think there is a way to merge persona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't partition.  Instead work on the query.

Long answer:

Note:  `FOREIGN KEYs` are not allowed in `PARTITIONed` tables.  However, the indexes they generate *are* allowed.

To get around the error message, simply change the pk to

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, venue_id)
```

Better set of indexes is to replace your two keys with

```
PRIMARY KEY(venue_id, id)  -- gets the clustering effect on venue_id
INDEX(id)   -- keeps `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.
```

Don't expect anything from `(5)` in `INT(5)`.  All `INTs` are 4-byte integers.  See `SMALLINT`; it is 2 bytes.  (etc.)  Shrinking the table size may help performance.

Show us a slow report; we can explain how to speed it up *without* partitioning.